# Who serves the young in a family?

Tags: tradition

Stories like the Ramayana and Mahabharata show people serving their elders such as brothers, parents or grandparents by:

- Pressing their elders' legs while they are sleeping.
- Guarding them while they are sleeping.
- Serving food and doing other things as they were given guidance by the elders.

I see the same kind of tradition even in the present time.

My question is: if the younger one is serving all the elders then who should serve the younger one? Or is there no one to serve him/her other than their spouse?

Comment: could you pls clarify what does this have to do with Hinduism?

Comment: @Sai Thought it can be seen in other religions too, I have seen this in epic stories like Ramayana. So, I think there might be explanation for this.. in HInduism way..

Comment: In case of parents and grandparents: younger serves them and they give him blessings and guidance. Younger doesn't need service because he is young! Actually parents and elders also supports and help younger but it is not called *serving*.